# Running multiple SSH sessions simultaneously in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm wondering if there is a better way to parallelize ssh sessions within a script. My bash program simply executes "newusers" command remotely across 30+ servers simultaneously.  The issue is,  it will randomly miss ssh to a few servers in the loop.  As if I'm hitting a system limit.   I tweaked a few parameters with no luck:

net.core.somaxconn=1024

limits.conf: - * - maxlogins 600

Here is a snippet in the script,  this will run 25 instances for user1 to user25 and the objective is to ssh to 30+ $SERVERS for each of the 25x users at the same time.  For example, I will check and user12 was not deleted on some 7 odd servers.

```
SSH="/bin/ssh -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -p 61313"

for i in $SERVERS
do
  echo "adding user user1 in $i"
  $SSH -tt $i "sudo echo \"user1:pass1:1313:1015::/home/user1:/bin/rbash\" | sudo newusers" &
done
#wait
```

Comment: Not related to your immediate problem, but `SSH="..."` and then using `$SSH` is very prone to serious bugs. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: As for the _immediate_ problem, consider adding `-vv` to your ssh command, and redirecting both stdout and stderr to a distinct file per-server; then review the log file for whichever server happened to fail. Adding output from that log to your question will do a lot of good towards making it answerable.

Comment: I'd also suggest using something like `xargs -P` for parallelization to let you specify (and adjust) a cap on the number of servers to log into at once.

Comment: (And bigger-picture, you'd do well to switch from one-off shell scripts to using proper administration tools; Chef, Puppet, Ansible, SaltStack, Disnix, NixOps, etc etc etc; I have strong opinions about which of them are better/worse than others, but using _any_ of them is better than what you're doing now).

Comment: There are already existing commands like [`pssh`](https://github.com/lilydjwg/pssh) to handle uses cases like this, aside from higher-level remote management tools like those mentioned by Charles Duffy.

Comment: BTW, did I read you correctly to assert that you're doing a separate SSH session not just per server, but also an additional concurrent connection _per user on that server_? That may be your problem: sshd has a cap on how many not-yet-authenticated connections it'll allow at a time, beyond which it starts closing them without completing the handshake. You _could_ work around that by reusing connections via `ControlMaster`/`ControlSocket` or such, but it'd be a lot more sensible to make each remotely-invoked shell check _all_ the users.

Comment: (sshd _can_ also be configured to have a cap on how many _authenticated_ sessions each user can have, but one would need to review your `sshd_config` file to determine whether that cap is active; this is another limit that ControlMaster/ControlSocket will work around).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  thank you for the quick responses.   To answer your question,  yes, the script is called by a provisioning server when a user account is deleted.  A user account can have multiple user ID.  If a user has more than 20 ID I encounter the issue.  So the script is called 20 times (one for each user) around 1 second apart,  so they run concurrently.    I set MaxStartups 500 in sshd_config but that did not help.  I will try ControlMaster workaround next.

Answer (score 0):

Charles suggestion to configure ControlMaster resolved the issue.  Performance increased dramatically!

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config

Host *
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist yes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel, try:

```
doit() {
  echo "adding user user1 in $1"
  SSH="/bin/ssh -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -p 61313"
  $SSH -tt $1 "sudo echo \"user1:pass1:1313:1015::/home/user1:/bin/rbash\" | sudo newusers"
}
export -f doit

parallel -o --retries 10 doit ::: $SERVERS
```

(If you do not use `-tt` then `-o` is probably not needed.)